# nodejs convert objects in json to lines of strings and store the lines in a text file

Tags: node.js, json

I need help converting an array of json into lines of text

This is the sample array

```
var links =
   [
      {
        "file_name": "Night shot of Barcelona, Spain.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/uMEags4.jpg",
        "full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/f4ppj9/night_shot_of_barcelona_spain/",
        "downloadId": "cln85w0k4zogv6a"
      },
      {
        "file_name": "Nostalgia.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.redd.it/lyxuxk2cemk41.jpg",
        "full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/fdaaua/nostalgia/",
        "downloadId": "cln85w0k4zogv6c"
      }
    ]
```

I want this in a text format like this:

```
https://i.imgur.com/uMEags4.jpg
  out=Night shot of Barcelona, Spain.jpg
https://i.redd.it/lyxuxk2cemk41.jpg
  out=Nostalgia.jpg
```

There are about 10k objects in the array.I'm planning to download them using aria2c

I'm using a loop like this.

```
links.forEach((link) => {

})
```

but I don't know what the next steps are.

**EDIT**
I used @uday method. But I stored the string in a variable and then stored the string variable into a file

```
ultUrls.map((link, i) => {
      txtstr   += `${link.url}\n\tout=${link.file_name} \n\tdir=${dir}\n`

    })
    fs.writeFile(datapath + '\\'+ 'aria2clinks' + '\\' + textname, txtstr, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: can you elaborate on "i want in text format" ? Do you want to convert it into single string ?

Comment: I want a text file with just the values of the json in each line

Comment: in same file or different file for each object ?

Comment: Same file. There are 1000s pf objects in the array

Comment: can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` / `forEach` to loop through `links` and write to a file(s) using `fs`

```
const fs = require('fs')
links.map((link, i) => {
  let data = `${link.url}\nout=${link.file_name} \n\n`
   // if you want to write each json data in to new file // replace fileName_${i} as first arg in appendFile()
  fs.appendFile('sample.txt', data, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
})
```

output: sample.txt

```
https://i.redd.it/lyxuxk2cemk41.jpg
out=Nostalgia.jpg 

https://i.imgur.com/uMEags4.jpg
out=Night shot of Barcelona, Spain.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. I just checked this now. But I modified it a little bit. Please check my edit